# Please make the top bar mod button go to a more useful page

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

The `mod` button in the top bar for moderators goes to `/admin`, which shows the history tab of the moderator tools. But I use that tab, well, let's say almost never (in fact, I wonder why it's there. I guess it might be useful for SE staff to watch over the moderators, but what use am I, as a moderator, supposed to make of it?).

I would like the `mod` button, and preferably `/admin` as well, go to a more useful tab. The tab I want to get quickly to is the flags, but there's already the number in a circle for that. Next in line is the links tab.

So, please make `/admin` redirect to `/admin/links`, and move the history to `/admin/history`.

Comment: I agree; if I click on the moderator button is not to see when other moderators took actions. The links page is probably a better choice, if it's not possible to go to the last visualized page.